# React // Axios // Express Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, api, express, ssl, axios

I am trying to make api calls to the backend but am running into a lot of difficulty.

I have been doing research and noticed a trend of using cors on the backend express to set the header and avoid this issue however, I am not seeing results in any of the documents I have looked at. I have an axios file to create an instance below:

```
export const axios = Axios.create({baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true },
timeout: 3000
});
```

(I have tried with the * instead of true and that did not work either)
My server.js file has app using cors() before all the routes.

I have tested with and without cors, both with the instance and inputing the header directly into the POST request but still no luck.

Post request:

```
const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        //First is url
       axios.post('/input', {user})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            console.log(res.data)
        }).catch(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
```

I am at a loss. Any help would be very much appreciated.
Would my next step be to set up a middleware?

Thank you.

Server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./conf.d/database');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//Test DB
db.authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log('Database Working'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error: ' + err))

const app = express();

//Cors allows helps with the blocking of SSL by browsers
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//   next();
// });
app.use(cors());

//Body parser
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Account routes
app.use('/user', require('./routes/users_route' ));
//app.use('/api', require('./routes/api_routes'));


const api_port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(api_port, console.log(`Server started on port ${api_port}`));
```

User Routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../conf.d/database');
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', (req, res) => 

    User.findAll()
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    );

router.get('/add', (req,res)=> {

    console.log(req.body);

    var Search_History = {"one" : [15, 4.5],
    "two" : [34, 3.3],
    "three" : [67, 5.0],
    "four" : [32, 4.1]};
    
    User.create({
        Search_History 
    })
    .then(user => res.redirect('/user'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
module.exports = router;
```

UPDATE: I receive an error 404 when making the post call

Comment: share your server code also. are you using app.use(cors())  like this

Comment: @sharunkk I just uploaded my server and routes file

Comment: do you have a code for 'input' uri ?.i don't see any code related to that. try with POSTMAN you will get a clear response from it.